# Missing a DLL or assembly reference - Windows.ApplicationModel - Constantly getting errors on this

Tags: c#

Not much other information other than I'm trying to copy this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/managing-appointments

And it's telling me that it can't find the type or namespace "Windows". Anyone know how to fix this or if there's a work around? It seems to be having the fit at "Windows" not the rest of it.

[image: This is what's being displayed.]

I've already checked the references, etc. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Check the documentation for the [Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments) namespace or any of the types within this namespace. The documentation tells you which assembly/ies your project needs to refer to in order to use types of this namespace...

Comment: You need to provide a little more context about your problem.

Comment: I can't find the thing in references. So I'm attempting to install the latest Windows 10  SDK. It should work based on information read elsewhere.

Comment: That didn't work, nor can I find the reference to add it to the project.

Comment: Have you checked out the sample UWP application at https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Appointments?

Comment: `var appointment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment()` is where it falls down, because I'm missing the dll. I've reinstalled the latest Windows 10 SDK, and it still will not function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve missing assembly.

1. If you know what DLL it is, you can import it directly by adding it as reference.
2. Make sure that the DLL you added as reference CopyToLocal property is true.
3. If the assembly came from Nuget Package and you just freshly downloaded the project from a repository like git, try right clicking the solution and select **Restore Nuget Packages**.
4. If your project does not have the right reference, try download it from the Nuget Package. Make sure that you install the correct version to your project.

In this case, it seems that your project is looking for a Windows.ApplicationModel namespace. Seems like you missed something in your setup. Please check this setup process of microsoft for UWP app development:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/get-set-up

Comment: I've gone through the set up multiple times. I am aware that it is looking for that namespace. That namespace is apparently missing. I cannot find it in references, and this is after a complete reinstall of everything, not just the SDK.